# Determine the Fourier transform of $f(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, transformation

$$f(x)=1, \text{ if } |x| < a \quad \text{ or }\quad f(x) = 0 \text{ if } \, |x| > a.$$

We use the formula
$$ {1\over 2\pi} \int_{\infty}^\infty f(\bar x)e^{i\omega \bar x} $$
So is $f(\bar x)$ the same as $f(x)$ ?? In an answer they integrated form $-a$ to a however I thought it is from negative infinity to a since $0$ can not be integrated.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful.  I really just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I understand now -! Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome!!!  My pleasure. And I am really glad I was able to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{i\omega x}dx=\int_{-a}^{a}1\,e^{i\omega x}dx+\int_{|x|>a} 0\,e^{i\omega x}dx=2a\,\frac{\sin(\omega a)}{\omega a}$$

Note that the integral $\int_{|x|>a} 0\,e^{i\omega x}dx=0$.

Also note, that in the integral, the symbol $x$ is a "dummy" variable only.   That is to say, we can replace $x$ with $\bar x$  as a dummy variable and the result retains.